# Error accessing my widgets.php in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm having trouble accessing my widgets to make adjustments and create new ones.

Accessing /wp-admin/widgets.php from my site shows the following error:

```
$my_query = new WP_query( array( 'showposts' => ''.$numposts.'', 'cat' => ''.$catid.'' ) ); ?> 

An error of type E_ERROR occurred on line 38 of the file /home/mysitegf/public_html/wp-content/themes/MythemeR3/template-parts/widgets-post.php. Mensaje de error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function have_posts() on null in /home/mysitegf/public_html/wp-content/themes/MythemeR3/template-parts/widgets-post.php:38
Stack trace:
#0 /home/mysitegf/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php(393): dg_recent_post_widget->widget(Array, Array)
#1 /home/mysitegf/public_html/wp-includes/widgets.php(1977): WP_Widget->display_callback(Array, Array)
#2 /home/mysitegf/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-widgets-controller.php(630): wp_render_widget('dg_recent_post_...', 'sidebar2')
#3 /home/mysitegf/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints/class-wp-rest-widgets-controller.php(122): WP_REST_Widgets_Controller->prepare_item_for_response(Array, Object(WP_REST_Request))
#4 /home/mysitegf/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(1140): WP_REST_Widgets_Controller->get_items(Object(WP_REST_Request))
#5 /home/mysitegf/public_html/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php(987): WP_REST_Server->respond_to_request(Obj
```

What is this error due to?

Comment: Call to a member function have_posts() on null - PHP is unable to call a method on null, it needs an object instead. Add a null check before calling the method.

Comment: It's problem from your theme **MythemeR3/template-parts/widgets-post.php** line 38.

Comment: thanks u guys, I have solved it by changing if($my_query->have_posts()) : changing to if ( have_posts() ) :